# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit) freezes ever time

Tags: dual-boot, 64-bit

I have recently installed 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 in my computer along with 64-bit Windows 10 (Dual boot). The Windows 10 is working perfectly. But whenever I login into Ubuntu and try to do something like update the Ubuntu or other softwares or even try to open the "System software updates" folder/program, the screen freezes. This is happening right from the day one of installing Ubuntu.

I am providing my Hardware configuration below-

1) Motherboard: BIOSTAR N61PC-M2S

2) Processor: AMD Athlon (tm) 64x2 Dual Core Processor 4000+

3) RAM: Transcend 2x2 GB DDR2 800 MHz

Please help me. I can not use the Ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: Do you have by any chance an NVIDIA GPU?

Comment: Yes, My motherboard has in-build NVidia Graphics card.

Comment: Try to open `System Settings --> Software & Updates | Additional Drivers Tab` and set the driver there to the open source Nvidia driver or the proprietary one and tell me if this fixes your problem of the hang ups. I had something similar as I had installed 16.04 on my desktop system, the mouse pointer only moved choppy and became partially non responsive.

Comment: Sorry, Videonauth for my belated reply. I also thank you for your suggestions. Your suggestion really worked!! I updated Nvidia driver (proprietary) and this fixed my problem.

Comment: Then let me write this as an answer so this can get accepted then the case closed :)

Comment: I have another question. I have installed some program in ubuntu (the program installed properly). But I can not see the name of some of those installed software in the program list by performing the following command in the terminal   dpkg --list. I also can not make a desktop shortcut of those program. Can you help me in this matter too.

Comment: Yes or others on the site can too, make a second question for that as a question should be only about one topic at a time so it is searchable for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The hang ups most obviously happen because of using the wrong video driver, I had this issue myself as i installed 16.04 on my desktop PC.

So open `System Settings --> Software & Updates | Additional Drivers Tab` and set the driver there to the open source Nvidia driver or the proprietary one.

This should fix your problem.